# In the manga, what piece is Chiaki playing at the beginning?

Tags: music, nodame-cantabile

In chapter 1 of *Nodame Cantabile*, it is implied that Chiaki is playing some Beethoven in preparation for the school concerto competition. We also get a snapshot of a score, which presumably contains what he is playing.

[image: score in chapter 1]

Do we know what piece Chiaki is playing? In the anime, he is playing Beethoven's Piano Concerto no. 5 ("Emperor"), and it is easy to recognise as he starts from the beginning of the first movement. However, the score here does not correspond to any section of the concerto that I can recognise, and in any case, we are not explicitly told what piece he is practising.

I tried skimming through [a copy of the piano part](http://imslp.nl/imglnks/usimg/f/f8/IMSLP33972-PMLP03875-Beethoven-Op073soloPeters.pdf) of *Emperor* and could not find a section that matched. Inputting part of this score into the Musipedia search engine also did not get any useful results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the first movement of Beethoven's *Piano Concerto no. 1*, which is not the concerto being played in the anime. Examining the section where the piano begins to play, we can see a correspondence between the [orchestral reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_(music)) (as shown in a piano part) and the bars of top line shown in the manga. The lower line corresponds to the opening of the piano part, although a couple notes at the very beginning are missing.

For comparison, here is the relevant section of [the piano part](http://hz.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/9/9f/IMSLP33362-PMLP04230-Beethoven-Op015PSptrs.pdf). The orchestral part (i.e. the first line) is marked with yellow brackets; the piano (i.e. the second) with blue. (Note that the score Chiaki is using has a different format from the one I found; his includes the orchestral reduction even when the piano is playing, and the reduction occupies a separate line.)

[image: score with markings]